# Junit: Testing Parent child entities

Tags: java, jpa, junit, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have an entity menu, with a child relationship Restaurant. I will to check if that there are restaurants with the Menu, the menu cannot be deleted, so I made this Junit Test:

```
    Restaurant resto = new Restaurant(menu);
    restaurantService.save(resto);

            menuService.delete  (menu);

            menu = menuService.findByMenuId(menuName);

assertNotNull (menu);
```

but of course I can't test this UserCase because I have this Exception:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails 



public class Menu {

...


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "menu", 
               cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
               orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Restaurants> restaurant = new HashSet<>();
...
}
```

and

```
public class Restaurant {

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "menu_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Menu topMenu;
..
}
```

Comment: can you show us your entities please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases, assert statements won't help. You need to use "expected" in order to check that deletion doesn't happen and exception is thrown.

```
@Test(expected=MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.class)
public void testMenuDeletionFailure()    {
\\invoke the method you need to unit test, there is no need of assertion statements
}
```

Try this..